# run apache on specific 192.168.1.x host , using local host dns

Tags: apache2, dns, localhost, virtualhost

I try to run apache on a specific "192.168.1.x" address, using a localhost dns server (`nameserver localhost` in /etc/resolv.conf).

If I do `dig @localhost www.mywebsite.com`, the name resolves to 192.168.1.67.

In ports.conf, I have this : 
    Listen 192.168.1.67:80

In /sites-enabled/000-default.conf , I change the default *:80 to this :

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.67:80>
```

But it doesn't work. Both www.mywebsite.com and 192.168.1.67 are unreachable.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Do you have a network interface up that is using that IP, on that machine? You can't bind to arbitrary addresses which are not assigned.

Comment: Please see new edit.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You've configured DNS to point to that address, but haven't specified the address exists.

Comment: Oh I see. No interface using that IP.   My machine's local IP is 192.168.205.128,  I can serve apache there.  So, it's not possible to serve elsewhere in 192.168.x.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to addresses which are not assigned to an active network interface.

If you want a virtual host, that is done with names, not addresses. In `ports.conf` you would leave the *Listen* value to the default, so it listens on all active interfaces. Then, in the enabled site config, you would use `<VirtualHost www.mywebsite.com:80>`, with your DNS server configured to resolve `www.mywebsite.com` to your network interface's assigned IP.